# Change connectionstring app.config

Tags: c#

I have make a form  for the user choose de the database for the application , i have use this app.config file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="primer" connectionString="Data Source=SQL-PC;Initial Catalog=contro;uid =sa;pwd = xxxxxxx" />
  </connectionStrings>
  </configuration/>
```

I have this code in C# using the string of the app.config :

```
      if (conexd != null && conexd.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {  MessageBox.Show("Conexion Cerrada"); }
        else if (conexd.State == ConnectionState.Open )
        {
            string stcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["primer"].ToString();   
            MessageBox.Show("Conexion Open" + stcon );
        }
```

The above code works fine , i have read many post here, but i don not understand how to write in C# to change user, password, catalog, in the app.config , i have try something like this :

```
        string catalogo, usuario, password;
        catalogo = "teste"; usuario = "sa"; password = "xxxxxx";
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        string modif =  string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["primer"].ConnectionString,catalogo,usuario,password);
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal);
```

I have test this way too :

```
    var miconex = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        miconex.DataSource = "SQL-PC"; miconex.InitialCatalog = "control";
        miconex.UserID = "sa"; miconex.Password = "xxxx";

        string saleconfritas = miconex.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(saleconfritas);
```

this make an string , but where i save this string value in the app.config or in the registry??

is config.save the rigth way?? Thanks by any orientation.

Alejandro.

Comment: Does it work?  Are you getting an error? By the way, instead of manually editing the connection string, you might want to look at SQLConnectionStringBuilder:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: no error simply dont save any changes , i have look SQLConnectionStringBuilder, but where i save the string?? in the app or in the registry , i want to configure in my app the datasource one time.